# UIImagePickerController is not presenting correctly in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

I'd like to present an UIImagePickerController with the following code:

```
self.pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.pickerController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:self.pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's working fine for iOS 7 and below, but in iOS 8 I got the following glitch:

1. While transitioning to the image picker controller (vertical cover animation), the background colour of the picker controller is invisible, revealing the presenting view controller beneath. After transition is finished, the picker's table view will be displayed abruptly without animation.
2. Sometimes, the picker's table view is not displayed at all, and instead I got a blank black screen. The navigation bar is still there, but no bar button items whatsoever, so user has to force quit the application.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: have you implemented any of the `imagePickerController` methods to see if this still happens?

Comment: Yes, I did implement `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Comment: I did the same thing in Swift and it works without any issues so I really don't know what is wrong with what you did.I implemented `didFinishPickingImage editingInfo`method and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`

Comment: Is there anything in the device console to give a clue?

Comment: @WaltSellers Nothing for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`, but for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, I got the following log:

*Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.*

Comment: I'm not sure about how to fix the first glitch, but the second glitch apparently occurred because I tried to reuse UIImagePickerController instance that has been displayed before. If I create a new instance instead, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I managed to find the cause and fix for these problems and want to document it here:

1. The first problem occurred when I tried to compile to iOS 8 device from XCode 5.1. I switched to XCode 6 beta 2 and now it's working just fine.
2. The second problem occurred when I tried to reuse an UIImagePickerController that has been displayed before. Create a new instance instead before displaying, and it would be fixed.

Cheers.