# UIImage picker controller in ios8 returns blank screen at second time

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

In ios 7 uiimagepickercontroller is working correctly but in ios8(5s) it shows

**"Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."**

and it returns only with blank black color page.

Comment: This might help! http://stackoverflow.com/a/25944572/656600

Comment: facing the same issue